# Ships:Biggest One Ever

Tags: naval

What was the biggest merchant ship ever created that dwarfed existing ones and still is considered a behemoth today?To clarify,It can be a Merchant vessel or a naval warship.(Also can be a list too)

Comment: This seems pretty trivial to look up: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_container_ships

Comment: You might want to define what you mean by "biggest". Does that mean largest by volume, displacement or length? Are you including gas/oil production vessels such as the Shell Prelude or just conventional ships?

Comment: @Semaphore Except that neither [Seawise Giant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seawise_Giant) nor the [Batillus-class ships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batillus-class_supertankers) were container ships.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Except that's equally trivial to look up too: [List of world's largest ships by gross tonnage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_world%27s_largest_ships_by_gross_tonnage). Like SteveBird said the OP should define "biggest".

Answer (score 2):

The biggest ships ever created are the oil super tankers. There is a famous book published in 1978 called "Supertankers!" which is all about these ships and is very interesting. The biggest ship ever was the supertanker *[Seawise Giant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seawise_Giant)*.

Progress in ship size has generally been pretty gradual, so there have not been many big leaps. One notable ship from the past was the [Oceanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMS_Oceanic_%281899%29) which was the largest ship in the world from 1899 to 1901.

Comment: "Progress in ship size has generally been pretty gradual", except that the current record-holder has held the record for 36 years...